# AdMob Initialization Delay

Tags: java, android, admob

When I initialize AdMob:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

   MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-123");
   ...
```

My application took 2 seconds more than the usual to load this Activity and got this in the Log:

```
W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=1 for 439ms
>
W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=0 for 441ms
>
W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=2 for 442ms
>
W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=4 for 442ms
>
W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=5 for 442ms
>
W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(java.lang.Thread, long, boolean) from Thread.java:4294967294 waiters=6 for 440ms
```

If I remove the initialize line all run fast without nothing in the Log.

(The ads work even with this error but the delay is annoying)

Someone know where this come from? I cleaned the project but nothing changed.